# SharePoint calculated field looking up values in 2 columns

Tags: sharepoint

We have 3 columns: Filename, Project and RA(which is a calculated column)

In RA we want the value Start Workflow if column Project doesn't contain -- or Project doesn't contain a space.

```
=OR(IF(ISERROR(FIND("--",[Filename])),
    IF(ISERROR(FIND(" ",[project])), "Start Workflow", "No"
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out

```
=IF(OR(Filename="--",ISBLANK(Project)),"No","Start Workflow")
```

Example Logical Tests
[image]

Comment: Yes this works great!!
I couldn't get my head around the brackets and the Or clause, and I didn't get the if(or().

I get it now

Comment: Awesome, don't forget to mark as answer and upvote.